# decompose with zoo function (time series in R)

Tags: r

I am working on google stock price data (from 1/1/2007 to 31/21/2017).

I want to decompose it to trend, seasonal and random.

Here is my code:

```
library(zoo)
library(fpp)    
setwd("C:\\Users\\Son\\Desktop\\Time series\\Data")
google <- read.table("GOOGL.csv",header=T, sep=',') 

log price
googlets <- zoo(google$Adj.Close, as.Date(as.character(google$Date),format = c("%Y-%m-%d")), frequency = 4)

log price time series
google_logprice <- log(googlets)
google_logprice_num <- coredata(google_logprice)

decompose_google = decompose(google_logprice_num, "additive")

plot(as.ts(decompose_google$seasonal))
plot(as.ts(decompose_google$trend))
plot(as.ts(decompose_google$random))
plot(decompose_google)
```

But when I run the code, it occupants some mistakes:

```
> decompose_google = decompose(google_logprice_num, "additive")
Error in decompose(google_logprice_num, "additive") : 
time series has no or less than 2 periods
> 
> plot(as.ts(decompose_google$seasonal))
Error in plot.window(xlim, ylim, log, ...) : need finite 'ylim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
> plot(as.ts(decompose_google$trend))
Error in plot.window(xlim, ylim, log, ...) : need finite 'ylim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
> plot(as.ts(decompose_google$random))
Error in plot.window(xlim, ylim, log, ...) : need finite 'ylim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
> plot(decompose_google)
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'ylim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In cbind(observed = xx, trend = x$trend, seasonal = x$seasonal,  :
number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)
2: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
3: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Could you help me to resolve it :( ?

Comment: The error says it all: `time series has no or less than 2 periods`. Periods in this case refers to years. Your data is too small and requires more time points

Comment: I use the daily data from 1/1/2007 31/12/2017. Is it too small?

Comment: Post a sample of your dataset.

Comment: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GOOGL/history?period1=1167584400&period2=1514653200&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d